# How do I simulate the Salesforce Mobile App in Chrome's Dev Console?

Tags: salesforce1-app, chrome

It used to be that we could open up the Chrome Developer Console, then hit refresh, and it would essentially pull up the Salesforce1 app.

However, we think with the Summer 20 release, we aren't able to get it to flip to the mobile app when we refresh. It instead flips to the Classic version. Does anyone know if this was changed and if there's a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. Salesforce retired the mobile web experience with the Summer '20 release. You can read the Knowledge Article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349471&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1).

As per now I do not think that you are able to test your developments emulating the mobile app on Chrome, even though they said that simulator builds of the Salesforce mobile app would be available to download.

Best regards!